# Assigning values to dictionary in python results with value in the wrong key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm programming my way through the [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) and I have encountered a weird problem. I want to find all the possible ways to generate a (natural) number from two natural numbers. I created a simple loop where I have noticed weird results. For example, 1 was generated from 3 and 1. Some investigation has resulted with this:

```
#Importing stuff I often use in my solutions/tests
from math import sqrt, log, floor, pow, fabs, factorial
from sets import Set
from random import randint
from itertools import permutations
import sys


dub = dict()

c = 0 #Counting the number of elements in dub[18], use to track changes
for i in range (1,10):
    if 18 in dub: #setting c = len(dub[18])
        c = len(dub[18])
    for j in range (i+1,10):
        pair = [[i,j]]
        v = i+j
        if v in dub:
            dub[v].append(pair[0])
        else:
            dub[v] = pair
        v = i*j        
        if v in dub:
            dub[v].append(pair[0])
        else:
            if i == 3 and j == 8: print 'here', v # The value that is added to dub[18] instead of dub[24]
            dub[v] = pair
        if 18 in dub and not c == len(dub[18]): #This is how I found that something is wrong.
            c = len(dub[18])
            print dub[18]
            print v,i,j
            raw_input()
```

Which result with this:

```
[[2, 9]]
18 2 9

[[2, 9], [3, 6]]
18 3 6

here 24
[[2, 9], [3, 6], [3, 8]]
24 3 8
```

The key I am supposed use is 24 but the list is placed under the key 18. Why is that so?

Answer (score 7):

You are reusing the same list for multiple keys.  The line

```
pair = [[i,j]]
```

creates a list containing a single pair.  This list is used in both `else` branches

```
else:
    dub[v] = pair
```

resulting in two different keys using *the same list object*.  Since it is the same object, appends to the list for any of those two keys are visible in the other one.

**Edit**: Here's a minimal example demonstrating this behaviour:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> a = []
>>> d[0] = a
>>> d[1] = a
>>> d[0].append(2)
>>> d[0]
[2]
>>> d[1]
[2]
```

The obvious fix is to assign only the pair to the name `pair`, and create a new list containing the pair whenever needed:

```
dub = {}
for i in range (1, 10):
    for j in range (i + 1, 10):
        pair = [i, j]
        v = i + j
        if v in dub:
            dub[v].append(pair)
        else:
            dub[v] = [pair]
        v = i * j
        if v in dub:
            dub[v].append(pair)
        else:
            dub[v] = [pair]
```

To further simplify this code, you can replace the `if`s by `dict.setdefault()`:

```
dub = {}
for i in range (1, 10):
    for j in range (i + 1, 10):
        pair = [i, j]
        dub.setdefault(i + j, []).append(pair)
        dub.setdefault(i * j, []).append(pair)
```

Comment: Your solution works but I still don't understand it. I use different keys but I append to the same list?

Comment: @Yotam: I added a hopefully explanatory example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `fromkeys`, it also causes this problem.

> data = dict.fromkeys([int(x) for x in row[1:]], [])

The solution is using `setdefault` instead of `fromkeys` to initiate the default value of dictionary:

> data.setdefault(idx, []).append((row[0], val))